# Where is the flash memory on the NodeMCU ESP8266 v3?

Tags: esp8266, flash, nodemcu

In the NodeMCU v3 specs it says it has 4Mb flash memory. In the ESP-12EX datasheet it says the MCU has no rom, but can boot from an SPI external memory.

However, I don't see any flash memory chip on the board, so I was wondering... where is it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ESP12 is a RF module which contains a microcontroller (the ESP8266), and a ROM chip (the 25Q128FVSQ according to [this picture](https://cdn.hashnode.com/res/hashnode/image/upload/v1656411485342/C3-mQUzdF.jpg?auto=compress,format&format=webp) I found of its interior).

[image: hi-res photo of the NodeMCU with shield on and off]

Picture from [here](https://blog.spacehuhn.com/nodemcu-vs-esp8266), which also has more details about the NodeMCU.

Answer (score 4):

It's covered by the can/shield.

On the picture below, the shield is removed. The IC in the right of the ESP is the flash.

[image: ESP32]

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP32)